# How to convert jpgs to RST for IDRISI Selva Image Processing

Tags: image, terrset

I would like to create a mosaic data set in IDRSI Selva however, my images are jpg.  Is there a way to convert these within IDRISI or otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

Try File -> Import -> Desktop Publishing Formats -> JPGIDRIS. You can then mosaic the individual imported jpegs now in Idrisi format.